# JS - Only trigger document.onkeydown function if input is not selected

Tags: javascript

I'm currently calling the `document.onkeydown` function to trigger a movement function using the W,A,S,D keys.

It is working fine using the following code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 68){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 83){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 65){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: true});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 87){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: true});
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 68){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 83){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'down', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 65){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: false});
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 87){
        socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: false});
    }
}
```

My only problem with this is when the user types a chatmessage into the html input then the charackter would still move.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter message..." id="chat-input">
```

Which way should should be used to check if the html is selected/active or not?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't set the events so much globally?

Comment: You can prevent bubling keydown event on chat message input

Comment: `if (event.target.matches(cssSelector) ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to test the active element with  `document.activeElement`. You can use `document.activeElement.tagName` and test to see if it is an input tag.

So something like

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if (document.activeElement.tagName !== "input") {
        if(event.keyCode === 68) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

That said, I recommend using `addEventListener` instead of attaching to `onkeydown` property. `document.addEventListener('keydown', function() { /*...*/ });` is better. That way you don't overwrite any other events for the document. It's just better practice. I'd only use `document.onkeydown` if you need to support IE8 or lower.